Jónsson functions for arbitrary ordinals
Kanamori, in his book The Higher Infinite, says that there exists a Jónsson function for an ordinal $\gamma$ if and only if there exists a Jónsson function for $|\gamma|$, where $|\gamma|$ is the initial ordinal for $\gamma$. He goes on to prove that under the axiom of choice there exists a Jónsson function for any ordinal $\lambda$, but his proof seems to assume tacitly that $\lambda$ is an initial ordinal (that is, a cardinal).
My question is: how to prove the equivalence between the existence of a Jónsson function for $\gamma$ and $|\gamma|$, or prove directly the existence of a Jónsson function for $\gamma$.
The problem is that I don't see how a bijection $b:\gamma \rightarrow |\gamma| $ induces a bijection on $ [\lambda]^\omega\rightarrow [|\lambda|]^\omega $, that is, preserves order of the sequences $\{a_i\}_{i<\omega}$.
Let $[\lambda]^\omega$ be the set of sequences $a:\omega \rightarrow \lambda$ with $a_{i}< a_{i+1}$ for all $i\in \omega$ and $\lambda$ any ordinal.
A Jónsson function $f: [\gamma]^{\omega}\rightarrow  \gamma$ is a function with the property that for any $y\subset \gamma $ with $|\gamma|=|y|$, $ \{ f(a)|a_{i}\in y\forall i\in \omega  \}=\gamma $.

Let $b:\gamma\to|\gamma|$ be a bijection. If $f$ is a Jonsson function for $|\gamma|$, compose it with $b$ (componentwise) on its domain and with $b^{-1}$ on its codomain.  (Typo in the definition of Jonsson function: $\lambda$ should be $\gamma$.)

@AndreasBlass I put more information in my question.  The probem is that if a sequence ${ a_i }{i<\omega}$ is of order type $\omega$, the sequence $ { b(a_i) }{i<\omega} $ can have order type of any countable ordinal

You're right. My attempted  proof was too simple, and I don't yet see how to fix it.

Here is an argument for the equivalence. It's easier in the case that $\kappa=\mathrm{card}(\gamma)$ is a regular cardinal, so let's consider that first. Fix a J'onsson function $f$ for $\kappa$. Fix a bijection $\pi:\gamma\to\kappa$. If $X$ is a set of ordinals, write ${^{\omega\uparrow}}X$ for the set of strictly increasing functions $a:\omega\to X$. Then define a function $g:{^{\omega\uparrow}}\gamma\to\gamma$ setting $g(a)=\pi^{-1}(f(\pi\circ a))$, if $\pi\circ a:\omega\to\kappa$ is strictly increasing, and $g(a)=0$ otherwise. I claim this works. For let $A\subseteq\gamma$ with $\mathrm{card}(A)=\kappa$. We have to see that $g``{^{\omega\uparrow}}A=\gamma$. So we may assume that $A$ has ordertype $\kappa$. Note then that because $\kappa$ is regular, there is a set $B\subseteq A$ of ordertype $\kappa$ such that $\pi\upharpoonright B$ is strictly increasing. But then for every $a\in{^{\omega\uparrow}}B$, $\pi\circ a$ is strictly increasing, and letting $B'=\pi``B$, then conversely, for every $b\in{^{\omega\uparrow}}B'$, we have $b=\pi(a)$ for some $a\in{^{\omega\uparrow}}B$. But $f``{^{\omega\uparrow}}B'=\kappa$, and therefore $g``{^{\omega\uparrow}}B=\gamma$, which suffices.
In the case that $\kappa$ is singular, there is a variant of the above argument. Suppose $\kappa=\mathrm{card}(\gamma)$ is a singular cardinal. Given $f$ for $\kappa$ and a bijection $\pi:\gamma\to\kappa$, define $g$ just like before. I claim this works again. For like before, given a set $A\subseteq\gamma$ of cardinality $\kappa$, we can find a set $B\subseteq A$ of ordertype $\kappa$ such that $\pi\upharpoonright B$ is strictly increasing, which suffices like before.
To see there is such a $B$, let $\mu=\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)$ and fix a strictly increasing sequence $\left<\kappa_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\mu}$ of regular cardinals, cofinal in $\kappa$, with $\mu<\kappa_\alpha<\kappa$ for each $\alpha<\mu$. We may assume that $A$ has ordertype $\kappa$.
I claim there is a sequence $\left<A_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\mu}$ such that for each $\alpha<\mu$, we have $A_\alpha\subseteq A$, $A_\alpha$ has ordertype $\kappa_\alpha$, $\pi``A_\alpha$ is bounded strictly below $\kappa$, $\pi\upharpoonright A_\alpha$ is strictly increasing, and for all $\alpha<\beta<\mu$, we have $\sup(A_\alpha)<\min(A_\beta)$
and $\sup\pi``A_\alpha<\min(\pi``A_\beta)$. For let us construct such a sequence recursively.
For $\alpha=0$, let us find an appropriate $A_0$. Well, because $\mu<\kappa_0$, there must be $\beta_0<\mu$ such that $(\pi``A)\cap\kappa_{\beta_0}$ has cardinality $\geq\kappa_0$. Fix such an $\beta_0$. For similar reasons, there must be some $\xi_0<\sup A$
such that $(\pi``(A\cap\xi_0))\cap\kappa_{\beta_0}$ has cardinality $\geq\kappa_0$. Fix such a $\xi_0$. Let $A'_0$ be a set of ordertype $\kappa_0$  such that $A'_0\subseteq A\cap\xi_0$ and $\pi``A'_0\subseteq\kappa_{\beta_0}$.
Then as in the regular case, we can thin $A'_0$ out to a set $A_0\subseteq A'_0$ of ordertype $\kappa_0$ such that $\pi\upharpoonright A_0$ is strictly increasing. (Enumerate a strictly increasing sequence $\left<\eta_\delta\right>_{\delta<\kappa_0}\subseteq A'_0$ by letting $\eta_0$ be the $\eta\in A_0$ such that $\pi(\eta)$ is minimal, then let $\eta_1$ be the $\eta\in A_0\setminus(\eta_0+1)$ such that $\pi(\eta)$ is minimal such, etc. Then set $A_0=\{\eta_\delta\}_{\delta<\kappa_0}$.)
Given $\left<A_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\theta}$ where $\theta<\mu$, note that $A'=\bigcup_{\alpha<\theta}A_\alpha$ is bounded in $A$ and $\pi``A'$ is bounded in $\kappa$. Using this, it is easy to slightly modify the preceding argument to obtain a suitable $A_\theta$.
Now let $B=\bigcup_{\alpha<\mu}A_\alpha$. So $B\subseteq A$, $B$ has ordertype $\kappa$, and note that $\pi\upharpoonright B$ is strictly increasing.

this equivalence do not make use of choice?

No, it doesn't. The proof in the regular case doesn't use choice, but the proof in the singular case does. However, it doesn't matter, because letting $\pi:\gamma\to\kappa$ be a bijection and $A\subseteq\gamma$ have ordertype $\kappa$, we can then work in $L[\pi,A]$ (which models ZFC) to find a set $B\subseteq A$ of ordertype $\kappa$ and such that $\pi\upharpoonright B$ is strictly increasing.
